# Unit Testing JSON responses in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I do:

```
$this->post('/v1/customer', ['area' => 'kil'])
        ->seeJson(['created' => true]);
```

But instead of created => true, I would like to do "NOT STATEMENTS".
Ex: parent!=null or created_at > '0000-00-00'

How can this be achieved?

Comment: obtain the json response, decode it and use PHPUnit assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does have a `dontSeeJson` function which would solve both of the examples you've listed (though possibly not a more general case) --

```
$this->dontSeeJson(['parent' => null]);

$this->dontSeeJson(['created_at' => '0000-00-00']);
```

If you need something more specific, I agree with @gontrollez - decode the json (`json_decode($this->response->getContent(), true)`) and test that.

Comment: Yes. Thats the way I went. Was hoping for a better way though. :)